# Can one use biblatex to print only title of related entry in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have biblatex print only the title of the related entry in the bibliography. Using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@Inproceedings{Frege1897a,
  author        = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title         = {Über die Begriffsschrift des Herrn Peano und meine eigene},
  booktitle     = {Berichte über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Sächsischen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Leipzig: Mathematisch-physische Klasse},
  date          = {1897},
  pages         = {361--378},
  volume        = {48},
  related       = {Frege1984h},
  relatedstring = {English\addspace title},
  shorthand     = {PCN},
}

@Inbook{Frege1984h,
  author   = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title    = {On Mr. Peano's Conceptual Notation and My Own},
  date     = {1984},
  pages    = {234--248},
  crossref = {Frege1984},
}

@Book{Frege1984,
  author     = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title      = {Collected Papers on Mathematics, Logic, and Philosophy},
  date       = {1984},
  location   = {Oxford},
  publisher  = {Blackwell},
  translator = {Black, Max},
  editor     = {McGuinness, Brian},
  shorthand  = {CP},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Frege1897a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

What I would like is have nothing past `... My Own'; i.e., omit "In:
Gottlob Frege. Collected Papers on Mathematics, Logic, and Philosophy. Ed.
Brian McGuinness. Trans. Max Black. Oxford: Blackwell, 1984, 234-248."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new related type.

- Add `relatedtype={englishtitle}` to your entry
- You could remove `relatedstring` and put it in our new `related:englishtitle` macro
- Make a `related:englishtitle` macro looking like:

  ```
  \newbibmacro*{related:englishtitle}[1]{%
    \entrydata{#1}{%
      \printtext{English title}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{title}}}
  ```

## Full MWE

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@Inproceedings{Frege1897a,
  author        = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title         = {Über die Begriffsschrift des Herrn Peano und meine eigene},
  booktitle     = {Berichte über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Sächsischen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Leipzig: Mathematisch-physische Klasse},
  date          = {1897},
  pages         = {361--378},
  volume        = {48},
  related       = {Frege1984h},
  relatedtype   = {englishtitle},
  shorthand     = {PCN},
}
@Inbook{Frege1984h,
  author   = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title    = {On Mr. Peano's Conceptual Notation and My Own},
  date     = {1984},
  pages    = {234--248},
  crossref = {Frege1984},
}
@Book{Frege1984,
  author     = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title      = {Collected Papers on Mathematics, Logic, and Philosophy},
  date       = {1984},
  location   = {Oxford},
  publisher  = {Blackwell},
  translator = {Black, Max},
  editor     = {McGuinness, Brian},
  shorthand  = {CP},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\newbibmacro*{related:englishtitle}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \printtext{English title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{title}}}
\begin{document}
\cite{Frege1897a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]