# Can one use title of related entries in both bibliography and abbreviation lists?

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow up to 2 answered questions: [Can one set up 2 kinds of shorthand lists in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407341/can-one-set-up-2-kinds-of-shorthand-lists-in-biblatex) and [Can one use biblatex to print only title of related entry in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414874/can-one-use-biblatex-to-print-only-title-of-related-entry-in-bibliography)

I'm trying to combine these answers to produce a sectioned list of abbreviations and a sectioned bibliography.

I would like to have the section of the abbreviations of Frege's works give not the German titles but the related English titles.

David Purton's answer to the second question, defining a `relatedtype={englishtitle}` and a `\newbibmacro*{related:englishtitle}` solves the problem of having the Frege entries in the bibliography give the English titles.

In the MWE below I tried to put `\usebibmacro{related:englishtitle}` in a new driver `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{fregeabbrevs}`, to print the English Frege titles in the section of the abbreviations list:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Inproceedings{Frege1897a,
  author        = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title         = {Über die Begriffsschrift des Herrn Peano und meine eigene},
  booktitle     = {Berichte über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Sächsischen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Leipzig: Mathematisch-physische Klasse},
  date          = {1897},
  pages         = {361--378},
  volume        = {48},
  related       = {Frege1984h},
  relatedtype   = {englishtitle},
  shorthand     = {PCN},
}
@Inbook{Frege1984h,
  author   = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title    = {On Mr. Peano's Conceptual Notation and My Own},
  date     = {1984},
  pages    = {234--248},
  crossref = {Frege1984},
}
@Book{Frege1984,
  author     = {Frege, Gottlob},
  title      = {Collected Papers on Mathematics, Logic, and Philosophy},
  date       = {1984},
  location   = {Oxford},
  publisher  = {Blackwell},
  translator = {Black, Max},
  editor     = {McGuinness, Brian},
  shorthand  = {CP},
}
@Article{Moore1899,
  author       = {Moore, G. E.},
  title        = {The Nature of Judgment},
  journaltitle = {Mind},
  date         = {1899},
  volume       = {8},
  number       = {30},
  pages        = {176--193},
  shorthand    = {NJ},
}
@Book{Lewis1918,
  author         = {Lewis, C. I.},
  title          = {A Survey of Symbolic Logic},
  date           = {1918},
  location       = {Berkeley, CA},
  publisher      = {University of California Press},
  series         = {Semicentennial publications of the University of California, 1868-1918},
  shorthand  = {SL}
}
@Collection{Beaney2013,
  editor    = {Michael Beaney},
  title     = {The Oxford Handbook of the History of Analytic Philosophy},
  date      = {2013},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location  = {Oxford},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Main primary sources categories
\newcommand*{\generateauthorcategory}[3]{%   
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{by#1}%   
    \DeclareIndexNameFormat{cat#1}{%     
        \ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifdefstring{\namepartfamily}{#2}}         
            and 
            test {\ifdefstring{\namepartgiven}{#3}}
        }%
        {\addtocategory{by#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}}       
        {}}%   
    \AtDataInput{\indexnames[cat#1][1-999]{author}}}

\generateauthorcategory{frege}{Frege}{Gottlob}
\generateauthorcategory{moore}{Moore}{G.\bibnamedelimi E.}

% Filter for other, i.e., not main, primary sources
\defbibfilter{notmainprimary}{%
not category=byfrege %
and not category=bymoore %
}

% Check to distinguish primary from secondary sources
\defbibcheck{primarysource}{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{1936}
{}
{\skipentry}}
{\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{secondarysource}{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{1935}
{}
{\skipentry}}
{\skipentry}}

% Generating entries for the 3 abbreviations lists
\DeclareBiblistFilter{fregeabbrevs}{
    \filter[type=field,filter=shorthand]
}
\DeclareBiblistFilter{mainabbrevs}{
    \filter[type=field,filter=shorthand]
}
\DeclareBiblistFilter{moreabbrevs}{
    \filter[type=field,filter=shorthand]
}

% Sorting the abbreviations lists
\DeclareSortingTemplate{fregeabbrevs}{ \sort[final]{ \field{sortshorthand} } \sort{ \field{shorthand} } }
\DeclareSortingTemplate{mainabbrevs}{ \sort[final]{ \field{sortshorthand} } \sort{ \field{shorthand} } }
\DeclareSortingTemplate{moreabbrevs}{ \sort[final]{ \field{sortshorthand} } \sort{ \field{shorthand} } }

%
\newbibmacro*{related:englishtitle}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \printtext{English title:}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{title}}}

% Drivers for printing abbreviations lists
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{fregeabbrevs}{%   
\usebibmacro{related:englishtitle}%   
\newunit\newblock   
\printdate}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{mainabbrevs}{%   
\usebibmacro{title}%   
\newunit\newblock   
\printdate}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{moreabbrevs}{%
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{}%
\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
\usebibmacro{title}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
\printdate}

% Environment for abbreviation lists, to italicize by \emph the shorthands
\defbibenvironment{abbrevs}
{\list
{\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
{\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
\setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
\renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\emph{##1}\hss}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

% Titles for 4 parts of Bibliography: two main authors, other primary sources, secondary sources
\defbibheading{subbibtitleonly}[\bibname]{%
\section*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abbreviations}

Full details of these works are in the Bibliography.

\printbiblist[env=abbrevs,title={Works of Frege}, heading=subbibtitleonly, category=byfrege]{fregeabbrevs}
\printbiblist[env=abbrevs,title={Works of Moore}, heading=subbibtitleonly, category=bymoore]{mainabbrevs}
\printbiblist[env=abbrevs,title={Other Primary Works}, heading=subbibtitleonly, check=primarysource, notcategory=byfrege, notcategory=bymoore]{moreabbrevs}

\nocite{Frege1897a,Moore1899,Lewis1918,Beaney2013}

\chapter*{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[title={Works by Frege}, heading=subbibtitleonly, category=byfrege]
\printbibliography[title={Works by Moore}, heading=subbibtitleonly, category=bymoore]
\printbibliography[title={Other Primary Sources}, heading=subbibtitleonly, check=primarysource, notcategory=byfrege, notcategory=bymoore]
\printbibliography[title={Secondary Sources}, heading=subbibtitleonly, check=secondarysource, notcategory=byfrege, notcategory=bymoore]

\end{document}
```

But the result yields no titles at all:

[image]

So, how to put the English title, "On Mr. Peano's Conceptual Notation and My Own," after *PCN*, and before the date?

Another couple of questions:

- There is a period after "The Nature of Judgment", but a comma after *A Survey of Symbolic Logic*; how can I make them uniformly commas?
- Can the comma be made to appear inside the closing quote of the title, i.e.: "The Nature of Judgment,"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{fregeabbrevs}{%   
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{englishtitle}
    {\entrydata{\thefield{related}}{\usebibmacro{title}}}
    {}%   
  \newunit\newblock   
  \printdate}
```

to get the English title.

Your punctuation is not uniform because all `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`s but `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{moreabbrevs}` use `\newunit` while the latter uses `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`. You can either define `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` and use `\newunit`; or you use `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` everywhere. What is better depends on what you want in the actual bibliography. If you want commas there as well, use `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`; if you want to keep the full stops there, you need to go for explicit `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` elsewhere.

The comma is moved inside the quotation marks if you load `babel` with the `american` language option.

Comment: For some reason I can only move the comma inside with `\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}` Using `\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=american]{english}` doesn't work. But alas I need `fontspec`; are the commands I'm using for `polyglossia` incorrect?  Or is there some other method for working with `polyglossia`?

Comment: @ss1789 In your MWE it is enough to just load `\usepackage[american]{babel}`. It also worked for me with `\usepackage{csquotes}`, the exact settings of `csquotes` are not relevant here.

Comment: @ss1789 Ah OK. You can use `babel` with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`, you don't have to use `polyglossia`. If you are writing in English I would even prefer `babel` over `polyglossia`. `polyglossia` support in `biblatex` is not perfect and `polyglossia` development seems to have stalled in recent years.